# ¿Cómo puedo conectar rails con SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails

Necesito que me orienten en cómo puedo conectar mi aplicación de Rails a una BD en SQL Server ya creada. He intentado de varias maneras y me da error de conexión.

Estoy Usando estas dos gemas:

`gem 'tiny_tds' y gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'`

y la configuración del `database.yml` está de esta manera:

```
development:
  adapter:    sqlserver
  host:       #mihost
  username:   #usuario
  password:   #mipass
  database:   #nombreBD
```

el error que me da es el siguiente:

> TinyTds::Error (Server name not found in configuration files)

De ante mano gracias!

Comment: Hola Angel, bienvenido a SOes, ayudaría mucho que agregues todos los detalles que mejor describan tu situación, copia y pega el error, menciona las versiones de los softwares que andas usando y todas esas maneras que has intentado, saludos :D

Comment: Alli agregue los detalles, de ante mano gracias

Comment: El problema sin lugar a dudas está con el `host`. dado que #mihost no creo que exista en realidad, habría que ver cómo lo estás poniendo en la vida real para darse una idea.  Menciona también que versión y edición del SQL Server utilizas.

Comment: bueno alli lo coloque como comentario, en #mihost tengo la direccion ip de la pc donde esta las BD, estoy usando SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Tienes acceso al servidor desde tu pc? Has probado a conectarte desde algún cliente sql? Podrías probar con  http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net si aún no tienes un cliente

Comment: La instancia tiene nombre? Tienes activo el protocolo TCP/IP?

Comment: Buenas, la instancia si tiene nombre, y si tengo activado el TCP/IP

Comment: Listo pude resolver, el problema eran mis dns, muchisimas gracias a Todos

Answer (score 1):

Todo se basa en la gema actual de tiny_tds 2.1, por lo que primero instalas la gema ya sea que lo agregues a tu Gemfile o lo instalas de forma normal

```
gem install 'tiny_tds'
```

o

```
gem 'tiny_tds', >='2.1.0'
```

Lo demás ya es más simple con el siguiente comando:

```
cliente = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'xxxxxxx', host: 'localhost'
```

lo demás se va resumiendo a un simple comando para hacer nuestras consultas SQL

```
result = cliente.execute("tuBaseDeDatos")
result.do
result = cliente.execute("SELECT * FROM unatabla)
result.each do |row|
puts row
end
```

Comment: Pero la solución que das es para ruby puro. El OP pregunta por una solución para Rails